# Why does g++ use movabs, and with a weird constant, for a simple reduction?

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, reduction, accumulate

I'm compiling this simple program:

```
#include <numeric> 

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto num_numbers = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]);
    return std::accumulate(numbers,  numbers + num_numbers, 0);
}
```

which sums up the integers 1 through 5 and returns that sum (i.e. 15).

I realize `std::accumulate` can have a bit of trickery in the implementation, but still, this is pretty straightforward. I'm surprised by what I get [when compiling this](https://godbolt.org/z/Voky51) (on GodBolt), though.

With `-O3`, and with C++ being a compilation-time-computation-oriented language, I get the expected:

```
main:
        mov     eax, 15
        ret
```

but if I go down to `-O2` - still some heavy optimization - not only do I not get this compile-time computation, but I see this strange piece of assembly:

```
main:
        movabs  rax, 8589934593
        lea     rdx, [rsp-40]
        mov     ecx, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-24], 5
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-40], rax
        lea     rsi, [rdx+20]
        movabs  rax, 17179869187
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-32], rax
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     .L3
.L5:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx]
.L3:
        add     rdx, 4
        add     eax, ecx
        cmp     rdx, rsi
        jne     .L5
        ret
```

Now `.L5` and `.L3` I get. The surprising thing are these strange `movabs` instructions, to and from `rax`. What do they mean and why are they there?

PS - I compiled using GCC 8.2 on an x86_64 with no `-march` set. If I add `-march=skylake` - the `-O3` gets messed up too! **Edit:** This seems to be a regression in GCC, see my [GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87543). Thanks @FlorianWeimer!

Comment: Hint: convert the numbers to hex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

8589934593 is 0x200000001 in hexadecimal, and 17179869187 is 0x400000003.  These two `movabs` instructions simply load two `int` constants into one 64-bit register each, for initializing the array on the stack.  You can disable this GCC optimization using `-fno-store-merging`, then you will get something like this at `-O2` for the array initialization:

```
movl    $1, -40(%rsp)
…
…
movl    $2, -36(%rsp)
…
movl    $3, -32(%rsp)
movl    $4, -28(%rsp)
movl    $5, -24(%rsp)
```

The lack of optimization to a single constant looks like a GCC regression, by the way.  I do not see this with GCC 6.3.  It could actually be related to store merging, which I do not think was part of GCC 6.

Comment: Bug report submitted about the regression - see link in my edit. If you're able to marked it as 'confirmed', I'd appreciate it.